# Delete Excel file in SharePoint 2010 library only by using VBA

Tags: delete, vba

I am having a excel workbook. When a person click on the marco the files are saves to two new folders need to delete a Excel file on SharePoint.

I have tried the "Kill" function in Excel VBA, but is says the file do not exist.

Kill function

```
Sub DeleteExample3()
'You can use this to delete one xls file in the folder Test
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Users\Ron\Test\ron.xls"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Do any one have success or a example by killing a file using VBA?!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First your code sample points to a file locally stored on a hard drive, not a SharePoint file.

I'm not an expert in VBA but if you want to delete a SharePoint file from within an Excel file (=client application) I would use/call the SharePoint web services. 
You can delete a file from a SharePoint list using the lists.asmx web service
http://{yourserver}/_vti_bin/lists.asmx

Make sure that the user has delete permissions in SharePoint

Comment: HI W0ut, It is correct that correct that i want's to delete a SharePoint file by clicked a macro in a Excel file. I will look into lists.asmx, and see if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to map a network drive to the sharepoint folder

```
Dim spMap As Object, spPath As String

Set spMap = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
spMap.MapNetworkDrive "X:", spPath
DoEvents

Kill "X:\Book1.xls"

spMap.RemoveNetworkDrive "X:", True
```

checking to see if it exists is a whole other matter...